# Best practice external script or files

Tags: php, html

I have my page structured in 3 components: header, menu, footer, and in some page I use some scripts in other no. My question is: The best practice is to put all the tags like `<script>` or `<link>` in `header.php at <header>` or it's ok to put the scripts I'm using in the page where I need? For example, I need to use TinyMCE just in 2 pages, is it OK to declare the tags just in this 2 pages or in `<header>`?

Comment: You should put your stripts in the `<head>` Tag or at the very bottom of your `<body>`, right before </body>. Keep in mind `<head>` and `<header>` are two very different things.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as off-topic/primarily opinion based. Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score -1):

Use your public script and css in header

Like frameworks structure.
Some css or script that is specific use soecific.

I suggest you use asset manager

https://www.google.com/search?q=asset+manager+for+php&oq=asset+manager+for+php&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.8416j0j4&client=ms-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8